# ICS with Cisco AnyConnect - cisco-anyconnect-win-3.0.4235-pre-deploy-k9.msi

Tags: windows, cisco-vpn

I've installed cisco anyconnect VPN  (cisco-anyconnect-win-3.0.4235-pre-deploy-k9.msi) on a 64 bit Windows 8 machine.  FYI, I do have internet access, while I'm connected to the VPN.

I want to share this VPN connection, so I can use some other laptop to access the VPN.  This is because, we are given only one VPN connection as a vendor, so more than one user (laptop) cannot VPN at the same time, which affects our productivity.

Is there any way to share this Cisco VPN connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not recommend doing so; using a shared VPN connection is conceivable. You would need to add another ASA (or concentrator / router) at the client site and implement a site-to-site VPN connection as [illustrated in this Cisco article](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a0080702999.shtml).

[image]